# Changing page with AJAX using JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh

I have the following problem. I want to move the user to another page when a certian condition is met. For example, I have a text input field where a user enters a URL. I want to move the user to this url, without him pressing any kind of submit form. I'm using AJAX to achive this. I have a function that checks for the pattern the user entered, if it is found to be a valid url, the page will change to this url. and if it's not a valid url, it will write error.

I have  a `<div id='url'></div>` that the AJAX updates with error message (on 1st load, before user entered anything) and this message continues until it a valid url was entered. when a valid url was entered, the following will be written to this DIV:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href="http://google.com";   // google.com is just an example
</script>
```

this doesn't seem to work. but if I put the page change code instead of the error message, it is working.

Why doesn't it work after a valid URL was entered?

Comment: it should be    <script type="text/javascript"> , sorry

Comment: How are you using Ajax here? What does it do? I see no reason to use Ajax (if you use it at all). Why don't you change the `location` directly?

Comment: @Felix Kling

The AJAX is working when a change occurs on the input form.

For example, if you typed "bla" it writes "bla is not a valid URL", this is working great.
But if you enter "http://google.com", it identifies the URL and writes:
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href="http://google.com"; 
    </script>
But nothing happens.

If I remove the URL pattern check and you write "bla", 
it writes
    <script type="text/javascript">
     window.location.href="bla"; 
    </script>
and transfer you to this url (and the browser won't find it of course...)

Comment: The "it identifies the URL and writes: <script type="text/javascript">" part is where you have your problem. Just execute the window.location change, don't write anything to the document.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any need for AJAX, just normal javascript. When you find that the entered text is a valid website and you want to load it, just use `window.location = "http://google.com";   // google.com is just an example` directly - no need to insert it into the document.

Comment: I know there is no need for AJAX here, I'm learning AJAX now and this is only for practicing. I will need to use it later on, on something similar to the project I'm working on and this is a small example to illustrate it

Answer (score 0):

Why do you write JS to DIV instead of just calling window.location.href="http://google.com"; ?

For example

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'answercheck.php',
  success: function( data ) {
    if (data=="correct"){
      window.location.href="http://google.com";
    }
    else
    {
        //show error message
    }
  }
});
```